# Rendering optimization in EmberJS

Tags: html, optimization, ember.js

I need to display about 1000 records returned by a single ajax request (No pagination) in a tabular view.

Since, there are two loops at play each for row and column, the rendering is taking too much time (about 10sec).

Using simple approach, Ember is taking too long to render view in this situation. Please suggest, what can I do to improve performance in this situation.

```
{{#each column in columns}}
  {{#each row in rows}}
    Some content
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Suggestions will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the optimization you are looking for is called "lazy-loading", in a nutshell, render the first 50 records, as the user scrolls, render another 50, etc, until all have been rendered.

Comment: Content could be loaded faster if you would avoid foreign keys and have data constructed for you in server side. So in order to have 1000 records you'd make a single request. DS.attr('JSON')

Comment: @SebastienDaniel I have specified no "pagination", I know this may sound stupid. But, need suggestions regarding how this can be optimized.

Comment: Where have you specified no pagination?! You could always use ic.ajax to retrieve custom queries that are not in synced with your project (also pagination).

Comment: @kristjanreinhold , I am getting the data in a reasonable time, from the server. The problem I have is the client side rending time.

Comment: @SudhirShrestha have you tried pre-compiling your templates? And pagination has nothing to do with lazy-loading... I don't understand your point.

Comment: @kristjanreinhold : Its in the first line itself. I have checked the network log and from there I can conclude it is much taking more time rendering than the total network peroid.

Comment: Could you post your template. Small things can make huge differents in rendering. For instance we had "link-to" helper in our search results template and it made rendering much more laggy :P

Comment: @kristjanreinhold : Even the template I have posted (without anything) currently takes more than 5 seconds. :(

Comment: Try using ajax for querying, no serialization in between.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you're looking is something like: https://github.com/runspired/smoke-and-mirrors

You don't need any pagination or anything it will render just the content that is visible and then when you scroll down it will render more content, look at the demos:

http://runspired.github.io/smoke-and-mirrors/#/examples/infinite-scroll

About the nested loop, maybe is reasonable to transform that dat inside the `setupController` method.

The code to implement this is really simple:

```
 <div class="table-wrapper dark">
  {{#vertical-collection
    content=model.numbers
    defaultHeight=270
    alwaysUseDefaultHeight=true
    useContentProxy=false
    firstReached="loadAbove"
    lastReached="loadBelow"
    as |item index|
  }}
      <div class="image-slide">
        {{examples/infinite-scroll/components/number-slide number=item.number index=index}}
      </div>
  {{/vertical-collection}}
</div>
```